# Find the Total no of votes polled in lakhs given the following conditions?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

In a election among $3$ candidates P,Q and R.P gets $120$% more votes than Q.P beats R by 3,50,000 votes.Q beats R by 5% of the total votes.Find the total no of votes polled in lakhs.

**MyApproach**

P gets $120$% more votes than Q.

=>P gets $11$/$5$  ....1

=>P beats R by 3,50,000 votes.   .....2

Unlike,First Eqn,the value is directly given.

Q beats R by 5% of the total votes.

=>Q gets $21$/$20$ x=The votes by which Q beat   ....3

Let,Total number of votes polled be x.

I am not able to form any relation.

> Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Comment: Jack.....lakhs ??? :)

Comment: Total number of votes in lakhs?

Comment: @imranfat Lakh is commonly used in India to mean 100,000

Comment: @jack If I have understood it right, then $P= 5.5$ lakhs

Answer (score 1):

The three equation are

> P gets 120% more votes than Q

$P=Q+1.2Q \Rightarrow P=2.2Q \Rightarrow \frac{P}{2.2}=Q\quad \color{blue}{(1)}$.

$1.2Q$ are $120\%$ of the votes of $Q$

> P beats R by 350,000 votes

$P=R+350,000 \quad \color{blue}{(2)}$

> Q beats R by 5% of the total votes

$Q=R+0.05\cdot (P+Q+R) \quad \color{blue}{(3)}$

P+Q+R are the total votes and $0.05\cdot (P+Q+R)$ are $5\%$ of it.

The third equation can be simplified. We can first collect the Q´s by substracting $0.05Q$ on both sides. And also collect the R´s.

$0.95Q=1.05R+0.05\cdot P$

Then solving (2) for $R$ gives $R=P-350,000 \quad \color{blue}{(4)}$

Inserting the expression for Q (1) and for R (4) in (3):

$0.95\cdot \frac{P}{2.2}=1.05\cdot (P-350,000)+0.05\cdot P$

Solve this equation for P. By using (1) and (4) you can calculate $Q$ and $R$, respectively.

Hint: $P=550,000$

Comment: I think equation 2 should be 350,000 not 3,500,000 since the OP is using lakh notation (comma before the hundred thousands place)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the hint. I will edit it.